# How to resend post multipart/form-data form with upload file to different server with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, post, multipartform-data

I am receiving a multipart file via http post in Java Spring. I want to forward that request with file to some other server. How can I do that in Spring java?

Answer (score -1):

In your jsp file:

```
<form ... method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and in your controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Long save(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                       @RequestParam String fileCode,...) throws IOException {

   ...

}
```

Comment: The OP asks how to take the request and pass it on to another server, not how to accept that request in general.